# Calling verifyPhoneNumber on my firebase ios app throws "internal-error"

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I use authentication by phone number in my flutter app. While it is working fine on Android I'm getting an error message on ios:

```
_firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        timeout: ...
        verificationCompleted: ...
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent
...

static final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
      (FirebaseAuthException authException) {
    Log.e(authException.message);
    Log.e(authException.code);
}
```

Code and message both only says it is an internal error without any details.

Everything worked find before I moved the app to a new Appel developer account. This means the team id has changed.

I've also changed the team id here:
[image]

I've downloaded the google.plist again and put it into the runner directory.

The google cloud platform also shows the correct team id:

[image]

The same team id is shown in xcode in "Signing & Capabilities" -> Signing Certificate.

Changing the team id also causes loosing access to the keychain:

> ITMS-90076: Potential Loss of Keychain Access - The previous version
> of software has an application-identifier value of
> ['MKYCXH32H9.com.sykori.framr2'] and the new version of software being
> submitted has an application-identifier of
> ['75GNKYT7HC.com.sykori.framr2']. This will result in a loss of
> keychain access.

But I think the only means that data from previous versions is not accessible anyomore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said the issue appeared after you switched developer accounts, it's safe to assume the issue is generated by a config error.

[Firebase Phone Auth for iOS docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth) specify a couple more steps than what you described above, namely:

1. Upload your APNs authentication key to Firebase. If you changed developer accounts APN auth keys also changed.
2. To enable Firebase SDK to use reCAPTCHA you need to add the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` to your `URL Schemes` box on the configuration page.
   [image]

These two steps I think will solve the issue, but just to be sure you could go through all the steps from the docs to make sure nothing else is missing.

Comment: "If you changed developer accounts APN auth keys also changed." I had overlooked that. Thank you.